# How to get a list of email addresses via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I'm developing a desktop app that needs to get the email addresses from an android phone via adb.
On older android devices I could use `adb shell service call account 4` to get the email address but as of Android version 8.0 that doesn't work.

How would I go about getting the email address via adb for modern Android devices?